# linking error cxx: cannot find -lvulkan

Tags: c++, ubuntu, linker-errors, vulkan

When I tried to compile example from Anvil framework for Vulkan I get following errors:

`[ 97%] Linking CXX executable OutOfOrderRasterization
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvulkan
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/OutOfOrderRasterization.dir/build.make:126: recipe for target 'OutOfOrderRasterization' failed
make[2]: *** [OutOfOrderRasterization] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/OutOfOrderRasterization.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/OutOfOrderRasterization.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2`

How i need to configure Vulkan to resolve it? (Ubuntu)

Comment: I can't quite see you pc screen from my country so you will have to show your code.

Answer (score 1):

Check you LIBRARY paths. You might need to download and install vulkan. There should a `.so` file in one your library paths(`/usr/lib{,64}`,`/lib{,64}`, `/usr/share/lib{,64}`) named to the effect of libvulkan.numbers.so.

See this ask ubuntu question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/796442/ld-cannot-find-lvulkan

Comment: So, I can just add to CMakeLists.txt:
`set(ENV{VK_SDK_PATH} "/home/kvark/tools/VulkanSDK/1.0.65.0")`
Is there a more elegant way to specify the path to the SDK ?

Comment: @KVARK You should be able to tell CMAKE to look in other directories for library paths. I've never liked having project libraries in my home directory. See: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html

Answer (score 0):

CMake versions 3.7 and later ship with a `FindVulkan.cmake` module that finds the Vulkan includes and library for you if you have a Vulkan SDK installed and the `VULKAN_SDK` environment variable set.  The CMake module also finds the includes and library if you have installed a Vulkan package to your system directories.  The [Getting Started guide](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/latest/linux/getting_started.html) on the LunarXchange website has some additional detail.